# How do you add multiple config files to configMap with kustomize configMapGenerator by using a pattern/regex/...?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, configmap, kustomize

Currently I do this:

```
configMapGenerator:
  - name: sql-config-map
    files:
      - "someDirectory/one.sql"
      - "someDirectory/two.sql"
      - "someDirectory/three.sql"
```

and I would like to do sth. like this:

```
configMapGenerator:
  - name: sql-config-map
    files:
      - "someDirectory/*.sql"
```

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 3):

Nope.

See discussion around that feature in [comment on "configMapGenerator should allow directories as input"](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/189#issuecomment-409042317)

The main reason:

> To move towards explicit dependency declaration, we're moving away from allowing globs in the kustomization file

Answer (score -1):

This command works fine and will edit your `kustomization.yaml`:

```
kustomize edit add configmap my-configmap --from-file="$PWD/my-files/*"
```

The `my-files` directory has to be in the same folder that the `kustomization.yaml` file.